# how to get window width and height with YUI?

Tags: yui

How do I get those values? I see the example on the YUI page to do this but using a click event, and then calling the get('winWidth') method on the event target. But how can I get these values without the use of any event? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.getViewportWidth();
YAHOO.util.Dom.getViewportHeight();
```

keep in mind you can reduce YUI namespace as shown bellow

```
(function() {
    var Yutil = YAHOO.util,

         Ydom = Ytil.Dom;

    Ydom.getViewportWidth();
    Ydom.getViewportHeight();
})();
```

Comment: In case you're using YUI3, the corresponding calls are `Y.one("body").get("winHeight")` and `Y.one("body").get("winWidth")`